# Flutter - The instance member 'remoteConfig' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to call a `remoteConfig` string inside my `List`

```
    class HomeModel {
      final RemoteConfig remoteConfig; //HomeModel() is called in Home() and fetches the param from there
      HomeModel({this.remoteConfig});
    
    List taskList = [
      { 
        'title': 'Hello',
        'url': remoteConfig.getString(''),
      },
    ];
}
```

However, it shows me the error -

```
The instance member 'remoteConfig' can't be accessed in an initializer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the initialization of `taskList` to `initState()`.

```
List taskList;

@override
void initState() {
    taskList = [
      { 
        'title': 'Hello',
        'url': remoteConfig.getString(''),
      },
    ];
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why we need to initialize inside initState method but not outside?